# Building elf within Eclipse within Windows

Tags: eclipse, gcc, build, binary, elf

I'm having trouble building an Elf file within Eclipse within Windows. It seems that everytime I build, a PE / portable executable for windows is created. I've gone into the Binary Parser section and checked Elf Parser while making sure that everything else is unchecked. However, I continue to end up with a PE which I cannot run on Linux.

For clarification, I'm using the Linux GCC toolchain within Eclipse.

I've attempted a reinstall of Cygwin -- still experiencing the same issues.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: On which os to you see that. Which compiler does eclipse use ? Did you make sure to have a cross compiler ?

Comment: I have Cygwin installed, which I believe Eclipse is using. I'm developing on Win 7.

Comment: I don't have access to a winbox right now, but to do the other way around I would call the compiler from migwin in the command line like this: `beco@/stackoverflow$ i586-mingw32msvc-gcc test.c -o test.exe` so you probably want to check if you can do analogous command in your command line prompt, and if so, check if eclipse can call the correct compiler