# How to set up Eclipse to cross-compile into Windows (from Linux x86_64)?

Tags: c, eclipse, mingw, cross-compiling, wine

I'm trying to set up an Eclipse (Helios) development environment that I can compile into an .exe binary for a Uni assignment.

Currently, I'm using Quincy 2005 under Wine, which works but the IDE is not as good as Eclipse, so I'm looking to switch over. Quincy uses MinGW's gcc to compile it's actual programs, so I was hoping there was a way to get Eclipse to use the same gcc (under wine).

I've noticed that Eclipse does have some sort of option for MinGW but it doesn't seem to be supported on Linux.

Does anyone have any instructions or experience on this? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need gcc under wine. Alike my comment here ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955617/building-elf-within-eclipse-within-windows ) all you need is to set eclipse to work with the correct gcc compiler. Look if you have this binary installed into your system, if you can run this command at shell: `beco@/stackoverflow$ i586-mingw32msvc-gcc test.c -o test.exe`. Then check if eclipse can call the correct compiler. Good luck.